# SSH into a server, run a command and save its output to a variable in Python

Tags: python, bash, ssh

I am translating a bash program to Python and have got everything up to the last bit working. Here is the bash code, which simply SSHs into a server, executes a PostgreSQL database dump, and if there was no error, saves it to a file.

```
output="$(ssh "$SSH_LOCATION" bash <<< "$(printf 'PGPASSWORD=%q pg_dump -U %q %q' "$pg_pass" "$pg_user" "$database")")"

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
then
    echo "$output"
    echo "An error occurred while dumping the database"
    exit $?
else
    echo "$output" > ~/"$LOCAL_DIR"/"$database"
fi
```

The variables `SSH_LOCATION`, `LOCAL_DIR`, `pg_pass`, `pg_user` and `database` are all defined within the Python program.

Escaping of the variables for the remote shell, especially `pg_pass`, is very important. This was handled in the bash code by `printf '%q'`.

What is the best way to translate the above bash code to Python?

Edit: and another caveat, the authentication is handled by public key, not password. Of course, the `ssh` shell command handles this automatically.

Comment: I want to say "throw subprocess at this". But I really would be at a loss if asked "exactly how?"

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I could do `subproccess.Popen(['bash', '-c', """BASH CODE"""])`, and feed all the variables from python. That feels a little too hacky though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a ssh connection with python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188970/how-to-make-a-ssh-connection-with-python)

Comment: You can also consider **pexpect**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best way to translate the above bash code to Python?

The answer to such question, more often than not, is: *use [plumbum](https://plumbum.readthedocs.org/)*.

Borrowing from the [docs](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/remote.html), which should be enough to easily demonstrate how you can use it (and how awesome it is), you can do something like:

```
rem = SshMachine("hostname", user = "john", keyfile = "/path/to/idrsa")
output = rem.which("ls")
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the simplest answer. All I had to do was your first line of code and then `print(rem["ls"]())` to get the output of `ls` remotely.

Answer (score 1):

Your python code would look something similar to the following if you want to use [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) to ssh into the box.

```
import paramiko
import copy

def ssh_server(server, username=username, password=password, pg_pass, ps_user, database):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(server, username, password)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("PGPASSWORD=%s pg_dump -U %s %s" % (pg_pass, $pg_user, $database))
    output = copy.deepcopy(stdout.readlines())
    error = copy.deepcopy(stderr.readlines())
    client.close()
    if not error and output:
        return stdout.readlines()
    else:
        print "An error occured\n%s" % error
        return False
```

The following code is just an example. It needs to be tweaked to your needs, of course. Paramiko has support for RSA keys as well as password. If you can ssh passwordless, you don't need to provide a password then and you take the password parameter out.