# getting stuck at os.read() inside a fork

Tags: python, multithreading, ssh, operating-system, pty

I have used the code below to create a child process, get inside an ssh container run a command inside the child and get its output.

```
import os
import pty

def wall(host, pw):
    pid, fd = pty.fork()
    if pid == 0: # Child
        os.execvp('ssh', ['ssh', host, 'ls', '/usr/bin/wall'])
        os._exit(1) # fail to execv

    # read '..... password:', write password
    os.read(fd, 1024)
    os.write(fd, pw + '\n')

    result = []
    while True:
        try:
            #time.sleep(1)
            data = os.read(fd, 1024)
        except OSError:
            break
        if not data:
            break
        result.append(data)
    pid, status = os.waitpid(pid, 0)
    #pid, status = os.waitpid(pid,os.WNOHANG)
    return status, ''.join(result)

status, output = wall('localhost', "secret")
print status
print output
```

Even though this works the first time you call wall() (or sometimes the first few times you call wall()), if you call wall() again it gets stuck at data=os.read(fd,1024) or at os.waitpid(pid,0).
Is there any solution to this working everytime I call wall().

*Note: I'm not allowed to use external libraries like pexpect, paramiko etc.*

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps sometimes os.read doesn't wait for the password prompt.
In that case only two options:

- Use a specialized package for connecting by ssh; for example [How to make ssh connection with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188970/how-to-make-a-ssh-connection-with-python)
- Parse the output and pass the password only after prompt. Try to debug the first call of os.read; probably that will clarify unstable behavior.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use external libraries, should've mentioned that in my question. The first call of os.read() returns the lines [sudo]: enter password and once we give in os.write(), it accepts the password and gets stuck at the next os.read. This only happens when you call the function multiple times. Things seem to work better if I give time.sleep(1) here and there but i was wondering if there was a better concrete solution that would always work.